# How do I separate local folders cloned from GitHub from regular, local folders?

Tags: git, github

I have a real newbie question, and I hope it's OK to ask it here.

I'm in the the process of learning to use GitHub, and I did 'git clone' of a bunch of folders into different places on my laptop.  Now I'd like to group them together, but am wary of messing up the hidden files. So I am wondering if there is a way for me to determine which folder can be locally dragged around and which is connected to Github.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Each time you do a `git clone` in a specified folder, you are associating a Git repository with that folder.  The top level folder can be placed anywhere you want, but you should not attempt to merge the contents of these folders together, which will cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Move Working Trees Freely

Given a directory structure like:

```
a
└── foo
    └── .git
b
└── bar
    └── .git
c
└── baz
    └── .git
```

you can move or rename the directories (a.k.a. "folders") *foo*, *bar*, and *baz* freely. The hidden *.git* directories (which are the actual cloned repositories; the other contents of each top-level directory represent your "working trees") will move along with their parent directories by default.

You can collect all of the top-level folders together as subdirectories. For example, assuming a Bash prompt:

```
mkdir ~/Documents/GitHub
mv -i /path/to/foo /path/to/bar /path/to/baz ~/Documents/GitHub/
```

Comment: Thank you! Believe it or not, the diagram helps--as does the actual Bash command. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just move the directories directly into one folder. Just don't merge directories.

All the data for the local repositories is stored in `.git`, which is inside the top-level directory of the local clone.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to be careful, but didn't know just what. And now I do.